# Workflow 4 with ASPNET: concurrency and status checking

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to model a request submission/ approval /completion scenario. I'm using a flowchart workflow hosted as a service in a console app using WorkflowServiceHost. The workflow has a service reference to a WCF Service hosted in IIS this second service interacts with the application database. I have an aspnet front end with a service reference to the hosted workflow service and call its methods from a proxy client.

The workflow is using a persistence database that I have created using the scripts provided.

The scenario is that a request for a service is made by a user. The request must be approved once by a specific person (I'm using a pick with a delay in one branch to remind the person if no decision arrives, the other branch is receive decision). For some services the request must have a second approval which can be done by any one of a pool of approvers. Once approval is all finished the request goes to a different pool of people for completion.

I have it working but 3 questions:

1. In the aspnet home page I have a list of requests with links to pages to approve/complete as appropriate and call methods on the proxy after which they redirect back but because it's all asynchronous I am having to manually refresh the home page to see the changed list. Am I stuck with forcing the page to refresh itself every x seconds to get around this or is there a way to make it synchronous/check state of workflow/wait for a message back? It's not terribly interactive just hitting a button and not knowing whether the action succeeded or not.
2. Is there a way to stop someone approving a request just after someone else in the pool has approved it? At the moment nothing happens for the second person when they hit the button (which is good). In the workflow persistence database I can see that the blocking bookmark is the next activity along (presumably set by the person who got there first) so it looks as though the second receive just doesn't happen. I have concurrency checking code in the WCF data service but this never fires because there is no attempt to update the database. I would like to be able to warn the second person that another user got there first.
3. My homepage list in the web app is built by querying the application database, but is it possible to query the workflow to find the status of each item, passing the item's id (I'm using the id as the correlation handle)? Is it normal to do this or do people usually just query the application database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I guess you could create an Ajax call that would check if any state change occurs and only refresh the page when that is the case.
2. If you send a WCF request for an operation that is no longer valid you should receive an error, unless you are using one way messaging because there is no message to send the error back. Mind you that due to a bug in WF4 the message could be a timeout after 60 seconds. There is no real way to avoid the problem because you are checking the workflow state as persisted and letting the user do an action based on that. Even when you query the state the workflow could have been resumes but not saved yet.
3. Either can work but I normally query the workflow instance store as that is the closest to the actual workflow state.

Comment: Thanks. 1)I did think about Ajax but not sure how to do it, will have a look for some tutorials  <br/> 2)I did try turning one of the Receives into a ReceiveAndSendReply (the Receives are all in the Trigger part of a Pick branch) but I just got the timeout as you described. This is rather a problem as concurrency is important. 3)How did you do this? I can see the blocking bookmark but I can't see the item ID - do I need to unencrypt something?

Comment: You can see the blocking bookmarks as is and if you use property promotion you cab extract other variables from the workflow and retrieve them from the database.

Comment: I've done some work on the asp side to wait for messages to come back. However I was once able to submit 2 Receives at once and so got my concurrency exception to fire from wcf. I tried to implement a Try Catch in the workflow but the workflow seems to go into faulted state even though it's catching the exception. I started trying to throw a FaultException defined as FaultContract but was getting error: No signature message parts were specified for messages... which I am stuck on. Must I use FaultContract and how do I stop the workflow faulting and just get an exception or message out to asp?

Comment: You can return a fault instead of throwing it in you workflow. The client will see the same behavior but the workflow will not fault.

Comment: I'm not throwing it in my workflow. Workflow calls a WCF service which calls methods to update the database. Those methods are where I throw a "stale data" exception. I can catch the exception in the workflow but the instance faults which I don't want. Sorry to ask so many questions I am really struggling with some aspects of WF.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the workflow call some code through WCF that throws. Basically that is the same as if the workflow throws because the exception bubbles up the callstack into the workflow. If you don't catch it somewhere it is an unhandled exception and that, by default, terminates the workflow.

Comment: I am catching it but the message is suppressed and the workflow seems to go into a suspended state even though I catch the exception. Is it normal for it to be suspended? Is there another way to do this - I just want to stop the 2nd receive from firing but it seems that if the client calls quickly enough before the bookmark is moved the second user could bury the first user's update if I wasn't throwing an exception.